# Gstreamer using appsrc and rtsp

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, rtp

We are streaming a video using **rtsp** using h264 encoding at bitrate of 90000 . We are able to get the stream in **vlc** media player but we are not able to get the stream when we are using Gstreamer pipeline.The gstreamer pipeline we are using is:

**! gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=8554 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink**

we also tried to play it using:
**gst-launch-1.0 playbin3 uri=rtsp://IPv4:Port_number**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open the stream using the playbin element. Make sure that when setting up the rtsp stream from VLC, you should add a stream path:

```
rtsp://IPv4:PORT_NUMBER/PATH
```

The gstreamer pipeline should also include this path in the playbin uri:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin3 uri=rtsp://IPv4:PORT_NUMBER/PATH
```

Other issues could be related to the firewall blocking the stream on the receiving side or the stream not being sent to the network that the receiving device is on.

Answer (score 0):

Sending side you are using RTSP but receiving side you are trying to receive RTP. Try the following command for RTSP reception.

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://IPaddress:8554 ! capsfilter caps="application/x-rtp,media=video" ! queue ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink -v
```

But your playbin solution supposed to work, try to check the error reason.